# Send data via POST request using Facebook batch API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to send data (like update status or post to friend's wall) to Facebook using Facebook's batch API. I wish to post to multiple friend's wall or something similar with just one call to Facebook API.

```
$users = array();

$users[] = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => '/me/feed', 'body' => "message=Test status update");

try{

    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($users), 'POST');

}catch(FacebookApiException $e){

    error_log($e);

}
```

But the script fails and the API call returns NULL. Can some one help me with the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because you don't pass a URL-encoded query string to the api() function. Using http_build_query() when building the array and urlencode() before the batch request will solve the issue.

```
$batchPost[] = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'relative_url' => "/$value/feed",
                'body' => http_build_query($body)
                );

$multiPostResponse = $facebook->api(
                '?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)),
                'POST'
                );
```

You can find a detailed tutorial on posting to multiple wall here: [Tutorial: Post to multiple Facebook wall or timeline in one go using Graph API batch request](http://25labs.com/tutorial-post-to-multiple-facebook-wall-or-timeline-in-one-go-using-graph-api-batch-request/)